# Python BeautifulSoup get request with double quotes in URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get BeautifulSoup to read this page but the URL is not passed correctly into the `get()` command.

The URL is https://www.econjobrumors.com/topic/supreme-court-to-%e2%80%9cconsider%e2%80%9d-taking-up-harvard-affirmative-action-case-on-june-10. But when I try to use BeautifulSoup to get the data from the URL it always gives an error saying that the URL is incorrect

```
response = requests.get(url = "https://www.econjobrumors.com/topic/supreme-court-to-%e2%80%9cconsider%e2%80%9d-taking-up-harvard-affirmative-action-case-on-june-10",
                            verify = False \
                            )  
print(response.request.url, end="\r")
```

It was the double quotes, “ (U+201C) and ” (U+201D), that caused the error. I've been trying for hours but still don't know to figure out a way to pass the URL correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the double quotes to single around the URL

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.econjobrumors.com/topic/supreme-court-to-%e2%80%9cconsider%e2%80%9d-taking-up-harvard-affirmative-action-case-on-june-10'  

r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')  

print(soup)
```

prints out the html as expected, I edited it to fit in this answer

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<ALL THE CONTENT>Too much to paste in the answer</ALL THE CONTENT>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem in just 5 mins.

Comment: Hi again, I'm not sure why but when I after running your code, it gives me a blank content

Comment: Do you get an error message or does the soup just return empty? Did it return with data the first time?

Comment: Thanks Joe, I got no error message only the empty return. In the first time I run your code, I only tried your suggested fix in the get command and it gave me no error so I thought it solved the problem.

Comment: Strange. Are you copying and pasting my code and just running that? What environment are you using? What operating system? I'm using a Windows machine and I'm running it in PowerShell with no issues.

Comment: I'm also using a Windows machine but running the code on Jupyter Notebook. I'll try and run your code again on another computer to see how it goes.